# Devise - "Escopar" tarefas do sistemas por usuário

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Estou fazendo uma aplicaçãozinha simples onde o usuário pode deletar, editar, visualizar e criar tarefas, as tarefas têm descrição, titulo e data que devem ser executadas.

Implantei o devise para fazer o cadastro de usuários e login de usuários, mas estou com dificuldade para "escopar" as tarefas por usuário, ou seja, o usuário fará o login e poderá visualizar, editar e deletar somente as tarefas criadas por ele.

Meu schema é:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170407164641) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "tarefas", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "titulo"
    t.text     "descricao"
    t.datetime "data"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_tarefas_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
  end

end
```

Utilizei belongs_to :user e has_many :tarefas.

Meu tarefas_controller:

```
    class TarefasController < ApplicationController

    before_filter :authenticate_user!

    def index
        @tarefa = Tarefa.all
    end

    def show
        @tarefa = Tarefa.find(params[:id])

     end

    def new
        @tarefa = Tarefa.new
    end

    def edit
        @tarefa = Tarefa.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
         @tarefa = Tarefa.new(tarefa_params)
         @user = current_user
         if @tarefa.save
            redirect_to @tarefa
         else
            render 'new'
         end
    end

    def update
        @tarefa = Tarefa.find(params[:id])
        if @tarefa.update(tarefa_params)
            redirect_to @tarefa
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @tarefa = Tarefa.find(params[:id])
        @tarefa.destroy

        redirect_to tarefas_path
    end

    private
      def tarefa_params
        params.require(:tarefa).permit(:titulo, :descricao, :data)
      end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def index
  @tarefas = current_user.tarefas
end


def create
     @tarefa = Tarefa.new(tarefa_params)
     @tarefa.user = current_user
     if @tarefa.save
        redirect_to @tarefa
     else
        render 'new'
     end
end
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem sua resposta. Você poderia explica-la? Clique no botão `editar` para edita-la.

Comment: Deu certinho, consegui! Obrigado pela respotta!